# Laravel migration add foreign key gives error foreign key (`user_id`)

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

When i `php artisan migrate` then i am getting an error see below.
Order migrations is users, companies and pivotmigration.

When i delete a `user` all `companies` has to delete and when i delete a `company` all `users` has to be deleted.

What do i do wrong?

User.php

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Companies.php

```
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('companyname');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->integer('housenumber');
        $table->string('postalcode');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('province');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phonenumber');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

CreateUserCompanyPivotTable.php

```
    Schema::create('user_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('user_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 

Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `user_company` add constraint `user_company_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration fail because the data type for `user_id` in `user_company` does not match with `id` in `users`.

You used `bigIncrement()` in `users` table which create a `auto_increment` field with `UNSIGNED BIGINT` as type.

In `user_company` table, you create `user_id` with `integer()->unsigned()` which create an `auto_increment` field with `UNSIGNED INT` as type.

MySQL needs two field to be same type when creating foreign key.

To solve this issue, you should create `user_id` with `bigInteger()->unsigned()` instead.

```php
Schema::create('user_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
    // You don't need separate schema code to create foreign
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: I changed also company.id to bigInteger and work like a charm, thnx!